# setTimeout, show and hide using jQuery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a large I want to display onload and then have it timeout to display smaller image.  then onmouseover, using jQuery slide in the large image and on mouse slide out the large image and slide in the smaller image.  Here is my code I have that only does the mouseover, mouseout function.  I need it to start with the large one displayed for 5 seconds and then slide into the smaller one.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".expanded").show();
        $(".collapsed").hide();


        $(".collapsed").mouseover(function () {
            $(".collapsed").slideUp(500);
            $(this).next(".expanded").slideToggle(500);
        });

        $(".expanded").mouseleave(function () {
            $(".expanded").slideUp(500);
            $(".collapsed").slideDown(500);      
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a global variable "readyforHovering" which will be set to false until the timeout expires such as:

```
var readyforHovering = false;



$(document).ready(function () {

setTimeout(function() {
  //Code to hide the large image and show the smaller image goes here

  //Now enable hovering...
  readyforHovering = true;
}, 5000);

        $(".expanded").show();
        $(".collapsed").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        $(".collapsed").mouseover(function () {
            if (readyforHovering) {
               $(".collapsed").slideUp(500);
               $(this).next(".expanded").slideToggle(500);
            }
        });

        $(".expanded").mouseleave(function () {
            if (readyforHovering) {
               $(".expanded").slideUp(500);
               $(".collapsed").slideDown(500);
            }

               });

    });
```

You don't want the user to be able to hover until after the 5 seconds has expired and you have shown the smaller image... that's the point of the readyforHovering variable.

Comment: that works exactly how I wanted it to work.  Thanks so much BBagi.

Comment: @D-Dawgg glad to hear it... go ahead and accept it as the answer, I promise you'll feel great for the rest of the day

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        toggleImage($(".expanded"));
    },5000);

    $(".collapsed").hide();

    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".collapsed").mouseover(function () {
        toggleImage($(".collapsed"));
    });

    $(".expanded").mouseleave(function () {
        toggleImage($(".expanded"));
    });


});

function toggleImage(img) {
    $(img).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(this).siblings("img").slideToggle(500);
    });

    return;
}
```